# <fieldset> breaking onChange in React form

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, onchange

I have a form inside of a React component, I have multiple onChange functions that DO NOT get fired. I did some debugging and realized it's due to the fieldset element. When I remove fieldset from the form, all onChange functions work, when I put fieldset back nothing works.

Here is my code:

```
//The function
handleChange(event) {
  console.log('change');
}

// The part of the form where I have onChange's. 
                    <fieldset> //When I remove this element, everything works. 
                    <h2>Account Information</h2>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-lg-8">
                            <label>Birthday</label>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="birthmonth" className="birthdateLabel">Month</label>
                                <select name="birthmonth" id="birthmonth" className="form-control required birthdateOptions" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
                                    {months.map(month => <option key={month.number} value={month.number}>{month.name}</option>)}
                                </select>
                                <label htmlFor="birthday" className="birthdateLabel">Day</label>
                                <select placeholder="Day" name="birthday" id="birthday" className="form-control required birthdateOptions">
                                    {dayOptions.map(day => day)}
                                </select>
                                <label htmlFor="birthyear" className="birthdateLabel">Year</label>
                                <select name="birthyear" id="birthyear" className="form-control required birthdateOptions">
                                    {yearOptions.map(year => year)}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>M/F?</label>
                                <select className="form-control required" id="sex" name="sex" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
                                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                                    <option value="other">Don't wish to identify</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-4">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Avatar</label>
                                <input id="avatar" name="avatar" type="text" className="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running the snippet, I'm not running into the issue:

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <fieldset> 
        <h2>Account Information</h2>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-8">
            <label>Birthday</label>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="birthmonth" className="birthdateLabel">Month</label>
              <select name="birthmonth" id="birthmonth" className="form-control required birthdateOptions" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                {
                  //months.map(month => <option key={month.number} value={month.number}>{month.name}</option>)
                  'month data'
                }
              </select>
              <label htmlFor="birthday" className="birthdateLabel">Day</label>
              <select placeholder="Day" name="birthday" id="birthday" className="form-control required birthdateOptions">
                {
                  //dayOptions.map(day => day)
                  'day data'
                }
              </select>
              <label htmlFor="birthyear" className="birthdateLabel">Year</label>
              <select name="birthyear" id="birthyear" className="form-control required birthdateOptions">
                {
                  //yearOptions.map(year => year)
                  'yearData'
                }
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>M/F?</label>
              <select className="form-control required" id="sex" name="sex" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
                <option value="other">Don't wish to identify</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-4">
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Avatar</label>
              <input id="avatar" name="avatar" type="text" className="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <SomeComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That made me think and I removed a few imports I have in my class and it seems to be import '../../../../node_modules/jquery-steps/build/jquery.steps.min'; causing the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to use jquery steps without this issue..